# I have list i want to delete with checkbox 1 or multiple and want to status 0 using Springs MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have list which is featch from database on jsp like  and i want to delete using checkbox with single row and multiple rows how to delete it with row id i have jsp code

```
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped dashboardtable" cellspacing="0" >
                                 <thead class="thead">
                                  <tr>
                                  <th class="head" style="width:14%"><span>Serial Number</span></th>
                                    <th class="head"  ><span>Images List</span></th>
                                    <th class="head"><span>Image Preview</span></th>
                                    <th class="head"  ><span>Email Id</span></th>
                                    <th class="head"  ><span>Sent Mail Time Span</span></th>
                                    <th class="head"  ><span>Resend Image</span></th>
                                   <th></th>
                                   <th class="head"><input type="checkbox" id="selecctall"/>Select All</th>
                                  </tr>
                                  </thead> 
                                    <tbody>
                                <c:forEach items="${emailImagesList}" var="al">


                                    <tr>
                                    <td style="width:14%">${al.serialNumber}</td>
                                    <td >${al.mailImageName}</td>
                                    <td><img  src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/emailImage/${al.id}/" height="100" width="150" ></td>
                                        <td>${al.emailId}&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/images/edit.png" onclick="showpopup1('${al.id},${al.emailId}');"/></td>
                                        <td>${al.mailSentTime}</td>
                                        <td><a href="#"  onclick="showpopup('${al.id},${al.emailId}');">Resend Image</a></td>
                                        <td> <img onclick="javascript:exportToForm('${al.id}')" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/images/delete.png" /></td>
                                        <td><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="${al.id}"/><a href="#" onclick="javascript:deleteToForm('${al.id}')" >delete</a></td>
                                    </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

and script is

function deleteToForm(id) {

```
             var del = confirm("Press Ok to delete!");
            if (del == true ) {

                window.location="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/deleteImageByUser?id="+id

            }
         }
```

how to get all table list id and how it status is 0

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: I have list which is featch from database on jsp like <c:forEach items="${emailImagesList}" var="al"> and i want to delete using checkbox with single row and multiple rows how to delete it with row id